# How to compare two PowerPoint (2010) text only like in word

Tags: comparison, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

1. Source (smart art, animation, formatting , casing)
2. Draft (smart art converted to shape, changed  formatting and casing, removed animation and transition and so on)

While I trying a compare to in PowerPoint that results is came all the changes. But I need only text changes (text inserted, text deleted)

Is there any way to change setting of track changes ?

Kindly help me...